# what matrix operation has notation $\oplus$?

Tags: matrices

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Generalization), a Jordan canonical form can be written in terms of its Jordan blocks as :

$$J=J_{a_1}(\lambda_1)\oplus J_{a_2}(\lambda_2)\oplus\cdots\oplus J_{a_n}(\lambda_n), $$

I was wondering what matrix operation $\oplus$ is? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the direct sum of matrices: ["Direct Sum of Matrices" at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_matrices).

To better understand this, you should read about direct sums of vector spaces: ["Direct Sum of Modules: Construction for Vector Spaces and Abelian Groups" at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#Construction_for_vector_spaces_and_abelian_groups).

Comment: Just a remark: sometimes the same notation is used for Kronecker's sum of two matrices.